# Using PHP to convert flat list of data to a hierarchy list

Tags: php

I have the following array element values that need to be converted from the line-by-line example to a more hierarchical approach.

From this:

```
(a)
(b)
(1)
(2)
(i)
(ii)
(3)
(4)
(c)
(d)
(1)
```

To the following:

```
(a)
(b)
(b)(1)
(b)(2)
(b)(2)(i)
(b)(2)(ii)
(b)(3)
(b)(4)
(c)
(d)
(d)(1)
```

I have tried several loops/ifs/while, etc, but can't achieve the result.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The app uses PHP, but I haven't found any solutions.

Tried this:

```
$elements = ['a', 'b', '1', '2', 'i', 'ii', '3', '4', 'c', 'd', '1'];
    $newElements = [];
    $currentMain = '';

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if (ctype_alpha($element)) {
            $currentMain = $element;
            $newElements[] = $element;
        } elseif (is_numeric($element)) {
            $newElements[] = $currentMain . '(' . $element . ')';
        } else {
            $newElements[] = $currentMain . '(' . end($newElements) . ')' . '(' . $element . ')';
        }
    }

    print_r($newElements);
```

and produces the following output which isn't correct.  The roman numerals may be causing the issue.

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => b(1)
    [3] => b(2)
    [4] => i
    [5] => ii
    [6] => ii(3)
    [7] => ii(4)
    [8] => c
    [9] => d
    [10] => d(1)
)
```

Comment: Asking the same question again after the first try was closed is not encouraged on SO.
Please by all means improve the question and ask for it to be reopened, but just asking the question in exactly that same way will get you exactly the same result, closure!

Comment: Ah I see my mistake, you have improve the question, but not waited for the old one you also improved to be reopened. I have reopened this one. Maybe you should delete the previous question to avoid others getting making the same mistake

Comment: _"The roman numerals may be causing the issue."_ - `ctype_alpha` is of course true for `i`, the same as it is for `a`. You are currently only differentiating between "alpha" and "numeric", but you still need to differentiate between "roman numerals" and "not roman numerals" in the former case.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better the logic that should be applied during that transformation? It' not clear to me what are the rules to create second array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the question is clear for me. I implemented an answer and tested it successfully.

Comment: @MilanG basically the goal is to differentiate between "levels", the first level consisting in alphabet numbers, the next level consisting of Arabic numbers and the third level consisting of Roman numbers. We need to display stuff in such a manner that each main level is displayed. If they have inner levels, then the main level is followed by the inner level where the main level and inner level is displayed. If an inner level has inner levels of its own, then repeat the process. I have implemented an answer for this logic and the test matches the expectation of the asker.

Comment: Is this sample data indicative of your real data?  I cannot imagine a real world application of what you are asking.  Why do you need these concatenated strings?  Do you _actually_ need something else?

Comment: @LajosArpad Please see the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78199751/revisions) and the complete lack of details as the question was originally asked. Thanks

Comment: @LajosArpad, yes it did lack details but the question was updated with additional information that helped get a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to figure out a structure that you can easily use for the display you need and then properly display it. Such a structure is to have a nested array of 3 levels, each level would have a key to describe what the node is and an items array for inner levels.

```
<?php

//Example input
$source = ['a', 'b', '1', '2', 'i', 'ii', '3', '4', 'c', 'd', '1'];
$target = [];
//First letter in alphabet
$nextLetter = 'a';
//Every index is initialized at -1 for leasure of increment and use
$letterIndex = -1;
$numberIndex = -1;
$romanIndex = -1;

//Looping the input
foreach ($source as $item) {
    //If the item is the next letter, then we need a new item on the main level
    if ($item === $nextLetter) {
        //We increment letter index and set a key-items pair at the new index location, the key being the current item and items being initialized as an empty array
        $target[++$letterIndex] = ["key" => $item, "items" => []];
        //Reinitialize indexes
        $romanIndex = $numberIndex = -1;
        //We jump to the next letter in our expectation at the first level
        $nextLetter++;
    //The second case is that we receieved a number
    } else if (intval($item) > 0) {
        //We store a key-items pair like earlier, but this time at a new index inside the items of the array located at letterIndex on the main level
        $target[$letterIndex]["items"][++$numberIndex] = ["key" => $item, "items" => []];
        //Reinitializing the roman index
        $romanIndex = -1;
    } else {
        //This is a leaf level, so we only store the item at the incremented index in the items array of the numberIndex-ed element inside the items array of the letterIndex-ed element
        $target[$letterIndex]["items"][$numberIndex]["items"][++$romanIndex] = $item;
    }
}

//Display
foreach ($target as $lItem) {
    //We display the main level upon each iteration
    echo "(" . $lItem["key"] . ")\n";
    //If we have inner items, we will loop them as well
    if (count($lItem["items"])) {
        foreach ($lItem["items"] as $nItem) {
            //We display the second-leveled element, using the first level
            echo "(" . $lItem["key"] . ")" . "(" . $nItem["key"] . ")\n";
            //We check if we have third-level elements and if so, we loop them and display them
            if (count($nItem["items"])) {
                foreach ($nItem["items"] as $rItem) {
                    echo "(" . $lItem["key"] . ")" . "(" . $nItem["key"] . ")" . "(" . $rItem . ")\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

In order to make this potentially infinitely deep I recommend the creation of a `Node` class or you could choose the name that suits you best.

```
abstract class Node {
    protected $key;
    protected $items = [];
    
    public function getKey() {
        return $this->key;
    }

    public function getItems() {
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function __construct($key) {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    //Implement this in subclasses and return boolean
    //Item should be a subclass instantiation of Node
    abstract public isCurrentLevel($item);

    public function addItem($item) {
        if ($this->isCurrentLevel($item)) {
             $this->items[]=$item;
        } else {
             //Make sure we never reach here with empty items array
             $this->items[count($this->items - 1)]->addItem($item);
        }
    }

}
```

Implement a `Node` subclass for each level, overriding only the `isCurrentLevel` method to check for letters on the first level, numbers on the second and roman nunmbers on the third, etc.

One problem I foresee is that values such as `i` and `v` and `c` and `l` are both letters and Roman numbers, so you might need to implement some tricks for `isCurrentLevel` like I did with the `$nextLetter`. Maybe capital letters for Roman numbers would be a good idea to avoid confusion.

Comment: Lajos - That's fantastic and works really well!  Thank you!  One additional item I forgot to mention (apologies).  The number levels are not always known before the data is sent to us for processing.  Is there a way for the code to recursively go through and pickup additional levels beyond the three?

Comment: @DanGlauber edited my answer and added a more general approach involving an abstract class (untested) which you will need to extend to subclasses representing the nodes of each level, implementing `isCurrentLevel` for each level separately, whereas the other methods would remain unchanged. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.